# Es posible asignar los datos recopilados por teclado a una clase fuera del main en c#?

Tags: c#

Quiero utilizar la variables `plaza` y `vehiculoArentar` en otras clases. Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Tipo de vehiculo que desea rentar:\n 1)Coche\n2)Microbus\n3)Vehiculo de carga\n4)Camion");
        int vehiculoArentar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Numero de plazas que requiere");
        int plaza = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (vehiculoArentar)
        {
            case 1: 

                break;
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, creo que este ejemplo es lo que estás buscando.

```
class Program { public static void Main(string[] args) {

            Console.WriteLine("Tipo de vehiculo que desea rentar:\n 1)Coche\n2)Microbus\n3)Vehiculo de carga\n4)Camion");

            // Instanciamos la clase que está fuera del main
            OtraClase miObjeto = new OtraClase();

            miObjeto.vehiculoEntrar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Numero de plazas que requiere");
            miObjeto.plaza = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (miObjeto.vehiculoEntrar)
            {
                case 1: 

                    break;
            }



        }
    }

public class OtraClase{
    public int vehiculoEntrar { get; set; }
    public int plaza { get; set; }
}
```

Saludos!!

Comment: gracias. saludos !

Comment: @TysonGolovkinMe alegra que te haya servido de ayuda, podrías por favor marcar con un signo verde la respuesta si ha sido válida por favor?
PD: el que haya marcado la respuesta como negativa podría dejar un comentario para poder conocer el motivo por favor? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si solo son dos variables lo mejor es pasar le esos datos a otra clase en el constructor :

```
public class OtraClase
{
    // Constructor :
    public OtraClase(int vehiculo, int plaza)
    {
        Vehiculo = vehiculo;
        Plaza = plaza;
    }

    public int Vehiculo { get; set;}
    public int Plaza {get; set;}
```

}

Y luego ya:

```
 class Program
 {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Tipo de vehiculo que desea rentar:\n 1)Coche\n2)Microbus\n3)Vehiculo de carga\n4)Camion");
         int vehiculoArentar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Numero de plazas que requiere");
        int plaza = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var otraClase = new OtraClase(vehiculoArentar, plaza). 

    switch (vehiculoArentar)
    {
        case 1: 

            break;
    }



}
```

}